# Flex Builder Plugin in Eclipse - Some Controls not available !

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

I downloaded Flash Builder from here : [Download](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder)

I recently started writing some small programs in Adobe Flash Builder Plugin for Eclipse.
I am trying out those programs by reading out the [Adobe book : Training from the source.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321529189)

But, I found that some of the controls mentioned in the book for some e.g, such as `ApplicationControlBar` doesn't appear in the Adobe Flash Builder 4. That control is mentioned in the book, but unable to find in the Builder.

What should I do ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you've created project using Flex 4 SDK which is default in Flash Builder 4. And the book covers Flex 3. So Flash Builder created spark Application container (from Flex 4) where `ApplicationControlBar` isn't actual anymore and replaced with `controlBarContent` property which allows to skin Application more flexible way.

So I can recommend you the following 3 solutions how to use Flex 3 (to be compliant with the book) in your project:

1. The easiest way to switch existing Flex 4 project to use Flex 3 is the following. Open project properties then `Flex compiler > Flex SDK version > Use a specific SDK` and select Flex 3 SDK which should be available there. Then you need to create new application in your project, select it as default using context menu, copy old application context to the new one and delete old application file. But I suppose it is better to create new project as far as you are dealing with sample apps from the book.
2. So just create new Flex project and select the right SDK version on the New Project master's first page.
3. If you plan to use only Flex 3 for your book's playground workspace you can set Flex 3 SDK as default so you won't need to select the right version on project creation. Just go to the `Preferences > Flash Builder > Installed Flex SDKs` and select the default version. You can go there right from the new Flex project wizard by clicking `Configure Flex SDKs…`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen or heard of an `ApplicationControlBox`. Perhaps they were referring to the [`ApplicationControlBar`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ApplicationControlBar.html) and that it's just a typo.

[Adobe has some great documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/class-summary.html) out there on each of its packages and classes. It's a great place to start if you ever have a question about one of the components.